# Error /vercel/path0/node_modules/mozjpeg: Command failed. Next.js app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I was deploying my next.js application as usual on vercel and got stuck on this error. I first thought was due to moment being used in the static pages, removed but still didn't worked, I then removed all images imported in certain pages and specified the public path in the src of the images, but build failed again. The logs are:

```
08:08:17.998    [4/4] Building fresh packages...
08:08:26.082    error /vercel/path0/node_modules/mozjpeg: Command failed.
08:08:26.082    Exit code: 1
08:08:26.082    Command: node lib/install.js
08:08:26.082    Arguments: 
08:08:26.082    Directory: /vercel/path0/node_modules/mozjpeg
08:08:26.082    Output:
08:08:26.082    Command failed: /vercel/path0/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg -version
08:08:26.082    /vercel/path0/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg: /lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /vercel/path0/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg)
08:08:26.082    mozjpeg pre-build test failed
08:08:26.083    compiling from source
08:08:26.083    Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ./configure --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-dependency-tracking --with-jpeg8  --prefix="/vercel/path0/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" --bindir="/vercel/path0/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" --libdir="/vercel/path0/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor"
08:08:26.083    ./configure: line 8028: /usr/bin/file: No such file or directory
08:08:26.083    configure: error: no nasm (Netwide Assembler) found
```

My package.json (i ran ncu -u on this very last one):

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "postbuild": "next-sitemap --config next-sitemap.config.js",
    "serve": "next serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.23.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.10",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "google-translate-api-browser": "^1.1.71",
    "imagemin-mozjpeg": "^9.0.0",
    "imagemin-optipng": "^8.0.0",
    "lazysizes": "^5.3.2",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "lqip-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "next": "11.1.2",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
    "next-optimized-images": "^2.6.2",
    "next-sitemap": "^1.6.184",
    "next-themes": "^0.0.15",
    "preact": "^10.5.15",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-cool-onclickoutside": "^1.7.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-leaflet": "^3.2.2",
    "react-markdown": "^7.0.1",
    "react-optimized-image": "^0.4.1",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.4.4",
    "react-toggle-dark-mode": "^1.0.4",
    "swr": "^1.0.1",
    "typeface-merriweather": "^1.1.13",
    "typeface-open-sans": "^1.1.13",
    "webp-loader": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.7",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
    "postcss": "^8.3.9",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.17"
  },
```

next.config.js

```
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");

const optimizedImages = require("next-optimized-images");

const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (isServer) {
      require("./scripts/sitemap-common");
    }

    return config;
  },
  webpack: (config, { dev, isServer }) => {
    // Replace React with Preact only in client production build
    if (!dev && !isServer) {
      Object.assign(config.resolve.alias, {
        react: "preact/compat",
        "react-dom/test-utils": "preact/test-utils",
        "react-dom": "preact/compat",
      });
    }

    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    optimizedImages,
    {
      domains: ["mars.nasa.gov", "www.nasaspaceflight.com"],
    },
  ],

  nextConfig
);
```

```
import Link from "next/link";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import {  SEO } from "@components/common";
import { getPostBySlug, getPostsSlugs } from "@utils/posts";


function Post({ post, slug, frontmatter, nextPost, previousPost }) {
  return (
    <>
      <SEO
        slug={slug}
        title={frontmatter.title}
        imageUrl={`${slug}.jpg` || `${slug}.png`}
        description={frontmatter.description}
      />

      <article className="px-4  max-w-screen-2xl">
        <header className="mb-8 mt-8">
          <h1 className="mb-2 text-4xl font-black leading-none font-display">
            {frontmatter.title}
          </h1>{" "}
          <time datetime={frontmatter.date} className="text-sm">
            {frontmatter.date}
          </time>
        </header>

        <ReactMarkdown
          className="mb-4 prose lg:prose-lg dark:prose-dark"
          escapeHtml={false}
          source={post.content}
         
        />

        <hr className="mt-4" />
      </article>

      <nav className="flex px-4 flex-wrap justify-between mb-10">
        {previousPost ? (
          <Link href={"/post/[slug]"} as={`/post/${previousPost.slug}`}>
            <a className="text-lg font-bold">
              ← {previousPost.frontmatter.title}
            </a>
          </Link>
        ) : (
          <div />
        )}
        {nextPost ? (
          <Link href={"/post/[slug]"} as={`/post/${nextPost.slug}`}>
            <a className="text-lg font-bold">{nextPost.frontmatter.title} →</a>
          </Link>
        ) : (
          <div />
        )}
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const paths = getPostsSlugs();

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params: { slug } }) {
  const postData = getPostBySlug(slug);

  if (!postData.previousPost) {
    postData.previousPost = null;
  }

  if (!postData.nextPost) {
    postData.nextPost = null;
  }

  return { props: postData };
}





export default Post;
```

If you need more information please tell me I will much appreciate any help

Comment: Can you build the Next.js app (`npm run build`) successfully locally?

Comment: After the build it was just saying on the last line loaded env file from... in development instead I'm getting this error `Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')` @juliomalves I also have provided the next.config file